# Round artboard corners in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, file-format, artboard

How can I round the corners of the artboard to follow the rounded rectangle that I have covering it? (the end goal is export it as a PDF)

Comment: You cant a pdf page is allways a square

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't.** Sorry, artboards are not "objects" and are *always* squared corner rectangles.

Answer (score 3):

Most common image file formats, PDF included, are rectangular in shape. Everything is contained inside a rectangle of a certain size. Then, some formats will allow transparency to be used, in which case you can have rounded corners in the actual artwork, but not in the actual file itself, which will still have sharp, 90-degree corners.

Comment: Most, nearly all i mean i im only aware of one exception to this and that is Ptex and that is not really a flat image at all.

Answer (score 0):

An artboard can't be rounded. A rounded rectangle is enough, and it can be used to achieve your purpose. It is how we design all kinds. I hope you understand.